# Add or Remove Polygons Based on Zoom Levels

Tags: javascript, google-maps

I am trying to add and remove polygons based on the zoom levels in Google Maps. This is what I am using to detect the zoom change in order to add or remove the polygons.

```
google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    if (map.getZoom() <= 13) {
        polygons.setMap(null);
    } else {
        polygons.setMap(map);
    }
});
```

The problem is the only one polygon is added, and only one polygon is removed. There are 3 polygons in total. If you remove the `zoom_changed` event listener, then all polygons will appear fine, but I cannot remove them based on zoom change.

Zoom in once to see the polygon. Zoom out twice to remove the polygon.

The JSFiddle can be seen here: http://jsfiddle.net/pc7tux02/5/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you are show and hide only the last polygon in your code. 
The solution is based on an array of polygons and a for cicle to show or hide all the polygons.  see this [jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5p233uux/1/) for the complete functioning version.

these are the main parts extract

```
var polygons = [] ;
var poly;
............

for (var j = 0; j < coords.length; j++) {
        var pt = new google.maps.LatLng(coords[j][1], coords[j][0]);
        bounds.extend(pt);
        path.push(pt);
    }
    poly = new google.maps.Polygon({
    path: path,
    strokeColor: "#FF0000",
    strokeOpacity: 5,
    strokeWeight: 5,
    fillColor: "#FF0000",
    fillOpacity: 0.5
});
polygons.push(poly);
path = [];

}

.........

 google.maps.event.addListener(map, 'zoom_changed', function () {
    if (map.getZoom() <= 13) {
        for (var k = 0; k < polygons.length; k++){
           polygons[k].setMap(null);
        }
    } else {
          for (var k = 0; k < polygons.length; k++){
           polygons[k].setMap(map);
        }     
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is your `polygons` is only storing the last polygon in your app. rather, make it into an array, and use `.foreach` to loop through your array when you want to update it.

Demo: http://jsfiddle.net/9vLcbm04/

Comment: Thank you. That clarifies the issue.